# Use a XML element position as a part of a URL?

Tags: xml, xslt

Is there a way I can use the position of an element in XSL as a part of a URL in html? I want to create a menu with all chapter-elements listed where the querystring is the position number, and the link text is the title-attribute.

This is what I want to do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="chapter">
    <a href='default.php?chapter='><xsl:value-of select="position()-1" />'><xsl:value-of select="current()/@title"/></a><br>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

This gives an error, but I think it illustrates what I want to achieve.

Comment: Please post a sample XML input.

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an "attribute value template":

```
<a href="default.php?chapter={position()-1}">
  <xsl:value-of select="current()/@title"/>
</a><br>
```

In an attribute on a literal result element, anything in curly braces is treated as an XPath expression to evaluate rather than a literal piece of text.  If you want a literal brace in an attribute value you must double it (`<example braces="some{{thing}}" />` in the stylesheet produces `<example braces="some{thing}"/>` in the output)

Comment: IMHO, an explicit `xsl:attribute` element would be more suitable for a beginner.

Comment: @user3016153 I've added another answer to fill the gaps, in this case attribute value templates are probably the way to go, and aren't *too* difficult to get ones head aroud. But alternatives never hurt.